# How to create database role that can select form any table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a database role named `SelectRol` , which the members of this `role` can `select` from any table.

I just know the syntax for create a member role and I don't know how to named it,

How can I create a database role named `SelectRol`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*  Using Object explorer--> Security -->Right click Server Roles --> Select New server Role after that you can grant permission and assign this role to users. */

   /* OR using TQL */



     Use master
        go
        CREATE SERVER ROLE [SelectRol] AUTHORIZATION [sa]
         GO

        ALTER SERVER ROLE [SelectRol] ADD MEMBER [user_name]
         GO

    /*Now Grant few permissions*/

Use master
go
grant connect sql to [SelectRol];
grant view any database to [SelectRol];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Object Explorer, expand a report server node.
Expand the Security folder.
If you are creating an item-level role definition, right-click Roles, and point to New Role.
Or, if you are creating a system-level role definition, right-click System Roles, and point to New System Role.
Type a unique name for the role. A name must contain at least one character. It can also include spaces and certain symbols, but not the characters ; ? : @ & = + , $ / * < > | " or /.
Optionally type a description. In Management Studio this description is visible only on this page. Users who view this item through Report Manager can see this description in that tool.
Select the tasks that members of this role can perform.
Click OK.